# Server.Transfer to internal virtual application

Tags: server.transfer

My question is how to manage several virtual applications, located at the same host

firstdomain.com is redirected to firstdomain.com/1
seconddomain.com is redirected to seconddomain.com/2
and so on...
each new domain must be located at different folder, and for now it is working fine.
But it causes some inconvenient, for example seconddomain.com/1 is showing firstdomain.com web site.

i'm trying to create something like dispatch at root directory "/" to transfer necesary domain with Server.Transfer("").

but it is not working like I thought:

```
Server.Transfer("/" + folder + "");
```

causes this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Error
>   executing child request for
>   /web_folder.
>
> Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Web.HttpException: Error
>   executing child request for
>   /web_folder.

```
Server.Execute("/" + folder + "");
```

causes error too:

> Error executing child request for
>   /web_folder.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Web.HttpException: Error
>   executing child request for
>   /web_folder.

both applications works fine accessed by its specified url.

and also there is a problem with two applications, if I use HttpModules from root web.config, it causes compilation error inside virtual application. It may be passed, if I add reference to same project in virutal site.

Any suggestions ?

i think there must be any solution, many people need to redirect any subdomain to a subfolder without Redirect, to keep the original URL dsplay

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `Server.Transfer` to an application that is hosted to a different virtual directory in IIS than the one that's performing the request.

Comment: what is the best solution?
it is possible to avoid .Redirect("/2") ?

Comment: I think thats because Server.Transfer keeps the original page in memory unlike Response.Redirect and each web app in ISS has its own separate memory domain

Comment: Can't you do these redirects at DNS level?

Comment: i only have virtual hosting, I dont think i have right on DNS server. I can only add/remove subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Server.Transfer can only happen for single HttpContext. Each virtual directory or app has its own HttpContext object and they know not that co-exists! so you cannot do that.